# libreoffice calc issues when trying to increase row height

Tags: libreoffice

When I increase row height using my mouse, it only affects the rows but not the spreadsheet itself. Am I the only one with this strange problem? I also have issues when I receive a spreadsheet with non-standard row height.

Specs: Libreoffice 7.3.7.2/Community, package 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.3. uname -r 5.19.0-43-generic Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.

[image: example]

Comment: This sure looks like a graphics glitch. Please include OS version and Libreoffice vesion in your question. I do not have such issues on Ubuntu 23.04 and never have seen such issues in the past.

Comment: Libreoffice 7.3.7.2/Community, package 1:7.3.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.3. uname -r 5.19.0-43-generic Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. Do you think reinstalling would solve this?

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Libreoffice 7.5. Can you try upgrading with the Libreoffice PPA?

Comment: Include the additional information in your question, not in a comment. Use "Edit". You also need to provide information on your graphical card. Likely indeed this is a graphical glitch and reinstalling won't help. Instead try temporarily creating a new account then see if the issue reproduces there. Probably yes, but if no, then we know for sure it is not a graphical issue but an issue with your specific user account.

Comment: I upgraded with the Libreoffice PPA as suggested by @ArchismanPanigrahi and this fixed the issue. I assume this means it was not an graphical card related issue? But it also means the original problem remains unclear.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be a libreoffice bug, and it was mentioned in the comments that upgrading with the libreoffice PPA solved the issue.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo apt install libreoffice libreoffice-gtk3
```